# get extension's human friendly description of a given extension

Tags: objective-c, file-type

I'm sure there's a way to get a human friendly description of a file's extension in objective-c - cocoa. For example: given an extension "pdf" to get "Portable Document Format", or given "app" -> "Application", or "txt" -> "Plain Text", etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with some the `UT*` functions:

```
NSString * humanReadableStringForExtension(NSString * extension) {
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)extension, NULL);
    NSString * extensionDescription = (NSString *)UTTypeCopyDescription(UTI);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    return [extensionDescription autorelease];
}
```

You can then do stuff like:

```
NSLog(@"pdf: %@", humanReadableStringForExtension(@"pdf"));
NSLog(@"txt: %@", humanReadableStringForExtension(@"txt"));
NSLog(@"app: %@", humanReadableStringForExtension(@"app"));
```

Which will log:

```
pdf: Portable Document Format (PDF)
txt: text
app: application
```

(woot, my 1000th answer!)

Comment: and it seems you've got more to give! Thank you!